# Online Pass not permitted

Tags: fifa-13

I have just loading up Fifa 13 and after signing in I have been greeted with the following message:

> We're sorry but you are not permitted to register an Online Pass which
>   is required to access all online features. For more information, visit
>   easports.com/onlinepass

There was no issue when I was playing this a few days ago, and now it wont let me access any of the online features.

What is going on? and what can I do to fix it?

NOTE: I have already redeemed my Online Pass and have played online many times before already

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I seem to have fixed the issue..

I went into the PSN store (not sure if this was a PSN specific issue or not to begin with) and they have radically changed the layout. Again, I am not sure if this was part of the problem is or just a coincidence. But I re-downloaded the Online Pass and started the game again and now the problem is gone.

For anybody else with this issue, I would suggest just trying to re-download the Online Pass

Comment: There seems to be some problem with the code verification, since every time I restart the game I need to re-download the code, and it usually works only after a few tries. Clearing the game data did not seem to have an effect. This is in Germany, and there might be some regional differences, I guess.